# Finding the volume of a function rotating around the x-axis. y = xe^(-x^2)

Tags: calculus, integration, improper-integrals, rotations

I was working on this question for a little while and I finally got it "done". However, I am not quite sure if what I did was correct or not. Here is the details:

- Consider $y = xe^{-x^2}$ being rotated around the x-axis. The question says:

**Does the resulting solid have a finite volume? If so, determine its volume.**

- My answer was yes, and here is what I've done:

  [Click Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CTCpl.jpg)

Comment: You are right; the calculation seems fine and the end result is correct. I suppose it would be easier if you used the substitution $2x^2=t$ initially, since the integral would reduce to a Gamma function and would be easier to calculate.

Comment: Maybe the part from $-\infty$ to $0$ is also being rotated.

Comment: @eye would you do it on the answer below so I can follow the steps you were talking about. Thanks

Comment: @AndréNicolas Oh that was my bad. I think the bounds were stated on the same question, but not directly (from a graph). It is from 0 to infinity

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Starting from

$$I=\pi \int _0^{\infty} x^2e^{-2x^2}dx$$

we make a substitution $2x^2=t$ which gives $4xdx=dt$, or $dx=\dfrac{d t}{4x}$. From $2x^2=t$ we get $x^2=\dfrac{t}{2}$ and $x=\dfrac{t^{1/2}}{\sqrt{2}}$ and therefore $dx=\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}t^{-1/2}dt$. Substituting gives

$$I=\pi \int _0^{\infty} x^2e^{-2x^2}dx=\pi \int _0^{\infty} \frac{t}{2}e^{-t}\dfrac{\sqrt{2}}{4}t^{-1/2}dt=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{8}\int _0^{\infty }t^{1/2}e^{-t}dt=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{8}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)$$

Where $\Gamma $ is the Euler gamma function. Using the property $\Gamma (n)=(n-1)\Gamma (n-1)$ we get $\Gamma \left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)=\dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)$ and the fact that $\Gamma \left(\dfrac{1}{2}\right)=\sqrt{\pi }$ we have $\Gamma \left(\dfrac{3}{2}\right)=\dfrac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}$. Therefore

$$I=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{8}\Gamma\left(\frac{3}{2}\right)=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi}{8}\cdot \dfrac{\sqrt{\pi }}{2}=\frac{\sqrt{2}\pi ^{3/2}}{16}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yep, you are correct that the volume is finite. The question is kinda ambiguous regarding the bounds, but since the range of the function is from negative infinity to positive infinity, my guess is that it is asking about the figure 
$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \pi (xe^{-x^2})^2 dx $$
Which is equal to twice the answer you got from your work (but still finite).

Comment: Oh that was my bad. I think the bounds were stated on the same question, but not directly (from a graph) 0 to infinity. So, would this make my answer correct?

Comment: Yep! What you derived is the right answer and it's finite.